# If one taxonomy contains the same term as another then display post

Tags: archives, terms

Say I have 2 taxonomies (main-tax-1, sub-tax-2), I want to display a post in an archive if main-tax-1 displays the same term as sub-tax-2 and vice versa.

I assume I'd have to add code in the functions file but where do I start?

Comment: Actually it sounds like you want to produce a custom archive template, or possibly modify your theme's archive templates or functions. The process might or might not also involve writing a function or functions for functions.php in your theme, among other further possibilities. Otherwise, in my experience it works best if you clearly state and visualize what you're trying to achieve (user does x, sees y and NOT z, is able to do x2,, etc.), then working backward from it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CKMacLeod. Right down to the bones, I have a soccer player listed under the ACTIVE club he plays for (displayed in archive.php). That's one taxonomy. When his club sends him on loan to another club, that's another taxonomy. I want him to be displayed under the ACTIVE club archive when that club is listed under LOAN club taxonomy and vice versa.

Comment: Pressed enter by mistake. I was actually going to add something but it's slipped my mind. That's the best description of the issue I can generate right now. I've had about 3 hours sleep, had a crap day at work, had my kids birthday and, right now, I have a cat meowing into my face. That's the best desc I can fathom.

Comment: Still unclear to me: Assuming you have two archives: ACTIVE and LOAN, why wouldn't the player or club who's in ACTIVE still show up in ACTIVE if also added to LOAN? Actually, it's not clear to me what is being displayed and how in either archive... I think you'll have to take the time on a better day to describe the situation in detail if you want a detailed/usable reply.